# What is the essential difference between Śaraṇāgati (शरणागति) and Prapatti (प्रपत्ति)?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, terminology

Sanskrit Kosha dictionary gives:-

> - [Śaraṇāgati](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/zaraNAgati?q=%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80)  (शरणागति): surrender
> - [Prapatti](https://kosha.sanskrit.today/word/sa/prapatti?q=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF)  (प्रपत्ति): Pious resignation or devotion.

Shri Shailacarya (18th century)  uses the words interchangeably in [Chapter 18](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/siddhanta-sangraha-sailacharya/d/doc427520.html) of Siddhanta Sangraha

> 161. The word ‘śaraṇa’ in the statement ‘śaraṇam prapadye’ **implies that ‘śaraṇāgati’ or prapatti** is not in need of any other means and can achieve the desired end by itself. This alone should be understood with this expression.

However, sometimes even synonyms have subtle difference between them. 
A famous example in Hindi language being - 'dayā (दया) & karuṇā (करुणा)'

> dayā (दया) = Sympathy - Mercy
> karuṇā (करुणा) = Empathy - Compassion

---

##### I'm looking for exact reference that either clearly state - "*Śaraṇāgati and Prapatti are same. No difference, they're just perfect synonyms.*" Or, a reference that explain any important/minute/ subtle difference between the two words.